# Using a regex in Java

Tags: java, regex

I need to build a regular expression for all nonempty sequences of letters other than : file, for,from.

So I should end up getting all the values from my text input excluding the above 3 words.

Is this a correct way to represent it?

```
^(?:(?!file|for|from).)*$
```

Also I was trying to use this regex pattern in my java program and assumed it should work. But it does not.

My sample code is as follows:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("^(?:(?!file|for|from).)*$");

// Split input with the pattern

String[] result = 

         p.split("file is not there from for this time for this test");

for (int i=0; i<result.length; i++)

    System.out.println(result[i]);
```

Is there an error in my regex or is there some error with the way I am using regex in java?

Please advise.

Thank you.

Comment: What do you mean by "nonempty sequences of letters"? Do you mean that you want all non-whitespace sequences that don't match the three keywords (which would include digits, punctuation, etc., but not whitespace)? All letter-only sequences that don't match (which would exclude digits, punctuation, whitespace, etc.)? Something else?

Comment: Why do you need a regex? Why not just read in the data and then remove the words file, for, and from?

Comment: What is the output you expected?  It's rather difficult to tell what your intent was from a broken regex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should do something like this:

```
String s = "file is not there from for this time for this test";
String[] splits = s.split("file|from|for");
```

Comment: Yep, do not underestimate the speed and ease of simplicity :)

Answer (score 0):

Unless your question learning RegEx, like Isac, I believe you are much better of simply splitting the string using a simple splitting algorithm and manually filtering away whatever entries you do not wish to find. `String.split()` is our friend. If the list of words to be ignored is large, consider keeping them in a HashTable and check each extracted word against this table. This will  transform your algorithm from `O(N^2)` to `O(N)`.

Not only will you be dealing with faster code that is easier to read, write and maintain (actually you haven't managed to get a working solution by now I guess).

My personal experience is, that most often your regular expression becomes very complex, hard to read and slow to evaluate due to the many unforseen backtracks due to the useg of `.`

Answer (score -1):

There is obscurity in the question.
Do you want to extract all the words of a string that aren’t one of (file,for,from) ?
Or do you want to match the strings that don’t include any of these words ?
’for’ is refused , but what about ’affordable’ : accepted or refused ?

As far as I understand the question, I propose, to catch words not being ’file’,’for’ or ’from’, in a chain, the following RE chain:

'\b(?!file|for|from)\w+'